# Why is Windows 10 randomly resuming from hibernate?

Tags: windows-10, hibernate, wake-up

I recently upgraded by Windows 7 Home Premium machine to Windows 10 Home. The upgrade went fine and the machine's been running alright, except for one thing: I hibernate it every night when I'm done using it, and Win 7 stayed "off" until I turned it back on again whereas Win 10 seemingly randomly turns back on.

I've disabled Wake-on-LAN as well as wake on keyboard/mouse movement. Windows Update is configured to have me schedule the updates instead of installing them automatically. There doesn't seem to be anything relevant in the Event Viewer, although to be honest I'm not 100% sure what I'd be looking for there.

So what gives? How can I diagnose these random wake-ups and stop them?

---

I did read through [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/975128/windows-10-pcs-start-in-the-middle-of-the-night) and checked out my scheduled tasks and maintenance settings. There are four scheduled tasks and none are configured to wake up the system. The automatic maintenance is supposedly configured to run at midnight, but that doesn't seem to be the case. I came home today to find my machine running and the maintenance run date is reported as 4pm:

> [image]

I also have the following in the Event Viewer:

```
The system has returned from a low power state.

Sleep Time: ‎2015‎-‎09‎-‎23T03:47:52.760473200Z
Wake Time: ‎2015‎-‎09‎-‎23T19:36:37.370293600Z

Wake Source: Unknown
```

This 4 p.m. wake-up seems to be consistent with previous wake-ups. WindowsUpdate ran about 3 minutes after the machine reportedly "woke up", so I'm not sure if that's what woke it up or if it just started running since the machine wasn't in use. I did also see [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/751544/computer-wakes-by-itself-but-wake-source-is-unknown), which matches the behaviour I'm seeing, but unfortunately the "turn off automatic updates" solution doesn't apply since that's already off.

Is this a dead end? What else can I look at?

Comment: If you disabled keyboard/mouse movements to wake, I assume you are using the power button to wake it from sleep state? I'd be curious to now what your usb power settings are.

Comment: @hydroparadise Yeah, I just hit the power button. I have two cats, so leaving wake-on-keyboard on isn't really an option. :) Where would I look up USB power settings?

Comment: Right click on the start window, select power options, then follow: Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Power Options\Edit Plan Settings. Once there, there's advance power setting option that opens the dialog that shows all available power options.

Comment: @hydroparadise All I got under USB there is "USB selective suspend setting: enabled".

Comment: Mine is set to disabled. Could make a difference? :)

Comment: @hydroparadise Changed now, we'll see! Thanks! You should post this suggestion as an answer in the meantime, just in case it works and I have something to upvote. ;)

Comment: Your pc will wake up to do maintenance and backups. Somewhere, you can change the time.

Comment: Check "Scheduled Tasks" See my answer [Windows 10 PCs start in the middle of the night](http://superuser.com/a/975136)

Answer (score 2):

Right click on the **start window**, select **power options**, then follow: **Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Power Options\Edit Plan Setting**s. Once there, there's **advance power setting** option that opens the dialog that shows all available power options.

Set **USB selective suspend** setting: disable.

See if that helps.

As an added note, there's a ton power options to dig through.  If the setting seems relevant, try it out. Windows has gotten pretty good about power options these days.

[image]

Comment: 2023 and Microsoft still allows computeres to go out of hibernante without any real/good reason...
Ont he screen above the last visible setting is really important too : wake timers. Speaks for itself. You can try that.
Also in devmgmt.msc (devices management) ALL devices with a power option can have "wake computer"... Should be disable (you can have 40 of that...).